# How can I restore 2.5TB mysql dump into AWS RDS MySQL in just few hours?

Tags: mysqldump, mysql-8.0

I want to restore the 2.5TB mysql dump into AWS RDS MySQL. Data is without create info and destination tables have only two columns.
Can anyone suggest the best strategy to restore the dump successfully?

Answer (score 0):

1. Adjust some database parameters, such as packet size, innodb and so on.
2. Annotate the statements related to the index, and build the index after importing the data.